# Django rest framework POST request followed by GET request

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, request

I am using django rest framework and I want after a POST request in a URL to follow a GET request to another URL with  processing some data coming from the POST request.

I attach my views.py:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from importer import event_import_data
from utils import optimization_solution

@api_view(['POST'])
def event(request):
    
        event_data_post = request.data

        return Response(event_data_post)

@api_view(['GET'])
def optimization(request):

        response_dict = {}

        event_data = event_import_data(event_data_post)

        response_dict = optimization_solution(event_data)
    
        return Response(response_dict)
```

So, initially I POST a json file in a URL and then I expect by using the dictionary provided by the POST request to use it in the GET request in another URL.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'event_data_post' is not defined
```

Any idea of what is causing the error and how can I bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

You're not saving the 'event_data_post' in your event method your just saving it temporarily if you want to save it you should have a model and a serializer and give your data to the serializer to save it in your model.

```
serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: What is SnippetSerializer?